# CASE STRUCTURE IN A DB2 SQL UPDATE

Tags: sql, db2

I need to update a value (FIELD_E) in one table based on the value in a field of a second table as long as certain conditions are met. Here is what I am working with thus far.

TABLE_1.FIELD_C is a primary key

TABLE_2.FIELD_D is a foreign key

There is a ONE TO MANY relationship between TABLE_1.FIELD_C AND TABLE_2.FIELD_D

```
UPDATE TABLE_1
SET    TABLE_1.FIELD_E = (
   CASE
          WHEN
                 (
                        SELECT MAX(FIELD_A)
                        FROM   TABLE_1,
                               TABLE_2
                        WHERE  TABLE_1.FIELD_C = TABLE_2.FIELD_D
                        AND    TABLE_1.FIELD_A IS NOT NULL
                        AND    TABLE_2.FIELD_B IS NULL) = 'Y' THEN '1'
          WHEN
                 (
                        SELECT MAX(FIELD_A)
                        FROM   TABLE_1,
                               TABLE_2
                        WHERE  TABLE_1.FIELD_C = TABLE_2.FIELD_D
                        AND    TABLE_1.FIELD_A IS NOT NULL
                        AND    TABLE_2.FIELD_B IS NULL) = 'N' THEN '10'
          WHEN
                 (
                        SELECT MAX(FIELD_A)
                        FROM   TABLE_1,
                               TABLE_2
                        WHERE  TABLE_1.FIELD_C = TABLE_2.FIELD_D
                        AND    TABLE_1.FIELD_A IS NOT NULL
                        AND    TABLE_2.FIELD_B IS NULL) = 'U' THEN '9'
          ELSE NULL
   END 
WHERE TABLE_1.FIELD_C = TABLE_2.FIELD_D
AND    TABLE_1.FIELD_A IS NOT NULL
AND    TABLE_2.FIELD_B IS NULL
```

I know I could probably do this more simply by just taking a snapshot and writing multiple statements using primary keys but if the values were to change after the snapshot and before the update, an incorrect update could be made.

Can I get some suggestions on how to do this using a similar case structures statement?

Comment: I'd consider using the `MERGE` statement instead.

Comment: Watch out, sub-select result with = comparison must never return more than 1 row.

Comment: @jarlhThe sub-selects are probably where my problem lies. I need every record that meets the conditions to update the field for that record.

Comment: A big problem is that your outermost `WHERE` clause mentions `Table_2`, even though you haven't given a table reference for it at that scope (not in the `FROM` or a `JOIN`).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is doing several things you likely do not intend, besides the blatant syntax and construction errors.  Making some assumptions about reasonable behavior, the query can be a lot simpler than your current effort:

```
UPDATE Table_1 SET field_e = CASE field_a WHEN 'Y' THEN '1'
                                          WHEN 'N' THEN '10'
                                          WHEN 'U' THEN '9'
                                          ELSE null END
WHERE field_a IS NOT NULL
      AND EXISTS (SELECT '1'
                  FROM Table_2
                  WHERE Table_2.field_d = Table_1.field_c
                        AND Table_2.field_b IS NULL)
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/593a6/2/2)</kbd>

---

Your original query had the following behavior or other problems:

1. Your subqueries were certainly returning more than one row (error)
2. Your outermost `SELECT` mentions `Table_2` without providing a reference (error)
3. There was no correlation between the outer `UPDATE` and any of the subqueries, meaning everything would be updated to have `1`, regardless of the actual contents of a particular row's field.

   - I'm also not sure if you want the `ELSE NULL` in your `CASE` - this has the effect of erasing whatever value is currently in `field_e` if `field_a` doesn't have a matching value.  Or rather, not restricting the update to those rows containing the values interested in (because `ELSE null` is implied if excluded).